# Having problems with 'sibiling' and 'not' selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have page that looks something like this

```
<h4></h4>
<table></table>  < want this
...              < want all these tables
<table></table>  < want this
<h4></h4>
<table></table>  < not this
...              < not these
<table></table>  < not this
```

I'm trying to select only tables under first `<h4>` element using this jQuery selector

```
$("h4:eq(0) ~ table.someClass:not(h4:eq(1) ~ table.somaClass)")
```

It doesn't work - returns all tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `div` to have an easier test-case:

```
$('h4:first').nextUntil('h4').filter('div').css('background', 'green');
```

http://jsbin.com/ipuvix/3/

Comment: Thanks! That nextUntil does the job!

Answer (score 0):

The selector would just be:

```
$('h4:first ~ table').not('h4:nth_child(2) ~ table')
```

Comment: That only returns one table, i need all of them under first h4 and none of tables under second h4 element

Comment: Oh OK I misread initially. I have edited my answer to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery [siblings selector](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) selects all of the siblings

```
$('h4:first').siblings('table');
```

Comment: That returns all tables since all of them are under first h4 element... I need tables under first h4 until second, all tables under second h4 elements need to be discarded

Comment: doh, sorry about that.  The answer is .nextUntil

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `Next()`

```
$("h4").next("table")
```